# How to use older version of Expo with the mobile app?

Tags: react-native, expo

i have a project using `expo` version `30.0.1` i don't want that to change the app was created using `CRNA` when i try to run `npm start` and i choose ios or android the expo mobile app on the simulator always gives me an error saying `the experience you requested uses Expo SDK v(null) but this copy of Expo Client requires that at least v34.0.0. the author should upgrade their experience to a newer Expo SDK version` now i want to run the app as it is with the older expo version, how can i achieve that?

i tried uninstalling the Expo Client app from the simulator but when it reinstalls it installs the newer Expo client app on the simulator. is there a way to tell Expo to install the Expo client on the simulator based on the current projects Expo version?

Answer (score 31):

**iOS**: according to the Expo support; it’s not possible to downgrade the expo client app on a device (apple does not let you distribute multiple versions of an app at the same time on the app store), but you can install it on your simulator by running `expo client:install:ios` in your project directory.

**Android**: you may download the required version from [here](https://apkpure.com/expo/host.exp.exponent) and install the APK. There is more info [here](https://dev.to/sasurau4/the-way-to-downgrade-expo-client-on-android-2mca) if needed.

Comment: dns error , not working