# Trying to Test React-Native Bug Only Appearing on Older Version of iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a react-native app that is working as expected on iOS 15. I have my iPhone 12 running iOS 15, and the Expo simulator is also on iOS 15. However, we have had a couple of reports of people running into issues on iOS 14. So my question is, how can I test this? Is there a way I can install a version of iOS in the Expo iOS simulator?

On this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61359724/how-to-use-older-version-of-expo-with-the-mobile-app) I see someone has responded with the following answer:

> but you can install it on your simulator by running expo `client:install:ios` in your project directory.

But that answer doesn't clarify how you pass a parameter regarding what specific version of iOS you want to install.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be on a Mac, setup xcode and install a simulator with target iOS 14.x. Then you can follow up with the approach from the answer you mentioned.

In xcode->Window->Devices and Simulators click on the + button in the bottom left. Select your Device type and pick an OS Version.

Comment: I edited my answer with the required steps.